# Where does Start-Job output go?

Tags: powershell

```
W:> $job = start-job { Write-Output "hi there"; throw "an error!" } | Wait-Job
W:> $job | select *


State         : Failed
HasMoreData   : True
StatusMessage :
Location      : localhost
Command       :  Write-Output "hi there"; throw "an error!"
JobStateInfo  : Failed
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : 882957a9-a5e0-4876-bd22-0dbd87512f10
Id            : 7
Name          : Job7
ChildJobs     : {Job8}
PSBeginTime   : 3/24/2013 5:52:41 PM
PSEndTime     : 3/24/2013 5:52:47 PM
PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
```

Where did my output go? How do I see the standard out/error streams?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Jobs are running in the background, so they don't write to the console. You have to run [`Receive-Job`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849718.aspx) after a job completes to collect its output.

Comment: Perfect. thank you sir. I would add that it seems it is important to wait for the job to be complete before trying to receive it.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Indeed. I added this detail to my answer.

Comment: I dont see this behaviour. Instead my console randomly gets a blast of output from the job. I'm not using Wait-Job though

Comment: You don't have to wait, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57692282/2476260).