# Start-Job - retrieve output in real time

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

We start a Powershell function via `Start-Job` and want to retrieve its output in the caller in real time. Is there a nice way to do so without calling `Retrieve-Job` in a loop?

Comment: By nature PS Jobs are "background" tasks, sounds like using Jobs may not be the best method for the task. Care to expand on the task so we know what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: `Receive-Job -Wait`

Comment: My understanding is that OP wants the job output in a `tail -f` fashion, thus looping Retrieve-Job... I don't think using Wait will do this?

Comment: There is no Retrieve-job FYI. He probably meant Receive-job but it will only return a finished jobs output AFAIK so looping it doesn’t really help.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$appJob = Start-Job { foreach($i in 1..10) { Write-Output "Testing $i"; Start-Sleep 10 } }
$appJob.ChildJobs[0].Output
```

Comment: What happens if jobs keep accumulating each time we run Start-Job without a foreach and we dont know which item in the array to use?