# Powershell- Read csv and write to SharePoint 2010 item. 1 million items... slow

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I've written a PowerShell script to import and read a csv file and then update a corresponding SharePoint 2010 Document Library item with the attributes found in the csv.

Everything works perfectly but I have the added complexity of needing to do this with over a million items. I've tested with 5,000 items and the entire process takes a few hours to complete. At this rate, it'll take over a month to do all 1 million+ items.

Is there a better way to write this script or am I stuck due to the insane number of items? My current script is below. Keep in mind that it is working... just slowly.

```
    $xlCSV=6
    $xls='z:\shared\Metadata.xlsx'
    $csv='z:\shared\Metadata.csv'
    $xl=New-Object -com 'Excel.Application'
    $wb=$xl.workbooks.open($xls)
    $wb.SaveAs($csv,$xlCSV)
    $xl.displayalerts=$False

    $SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://client.contoso.com" -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
    $SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["Shared Documents"]

    foreach($i in Import-CSV 'z:\shared\Metadata.csv')
    {
    $SPItem = $SPList.Items | Where { $_["Name"] -eq $i."Document Name" }
    $SPItem["Metadata1"] = $i."META 1"
    $SPItem["Metadata2"] = $i."META 2"
    $SPItem["Metadata3"] = $i."META 3"
    $SPItem["Metadata4"] = $i."META 4"
    $SPItem["Metadata5"] = $i."META 5"
    $SPItem["Metadata6"] = $i."META 6"
    $SPItem["Metadata7"] = $i."META 7"
    $SPItem["Metadata8"] = $i."META 8"
    $SPItem.Update()
    }

    Stop-SPAssignment $SPAssignment
    $xl.quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
    $xl = $null
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    Remove-Item "z:\shared\Metadata.csv" -force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps break this up into *n* number of csv's, and run the same operation in parallel using background jobs, there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel). So, put your workhorse code into a function or scriptblock, and pass each background job a link to a csv file to do it's uploading. I don't have access to a sharepoint server to test any code at the moment, but this is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion, Mike. Do you think importing the Excel file into SQL and then running the million+ queries against SQL would help speed the process up at all?

Comment: Not really, it would probably just add more complication if anything. Be aware also that you don't want 1M csv files and run them in parallel, you want to break them up into manageable chunks, and even then it may still take a few hours, but that's better than *several months*. I would experiment with different sizes, or just pick some number (like 5000 per csv) and kick it off over the weekend.