# Unzipping works on singlethread, but not multithread

Tags: multithreading, powershell, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a ton of files using PowerShell. I figured this is a great place to parallelize. However, my attempt to parallelize seems to make the unzip have no effect, even though it worked in the single threaded mode.

```
$unzip = {
    param([string]$sourceFile, [string]$destinationDir)
    #Clean out the destination if it exists
    rmdir $destination -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    mkdir $destination -Force

    #Actual unzip
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipFile = $shell.NameSpace($sourceFile)
    $destinationDir = $shell.NameSpace($destination)
    $destinationDir.copyhere($zipFile.items())
}

foreach($file in $files){
    $args = ($file.FullName, $destinationDir)
    Start-Job $unzip -ArgumentList $args
}

#Cleanup
While (Get-Job -State "Running") { Start-Sleep 2 }
Remove-Job *
```

When I run this without the multithreaded code, it works fine, but with it none of the files actually get unzipped. Why is this?

Comment: This may get better answers on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: It's highly unlikely that using multiple threads will give you a significant performance improvement. Typically, decompressing is very fast but writing the decompressed data to the disk drive is very slow. And because the disk drive can only do one thing at a time, what happens is that your threads spend most of their time waiting for the disk drive to be available. You're probably better off just doing it single-threaded.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, but I've already done that. I figured I might challenge myself and make it multi-threaded, but I cant figure out how to make it work.

Comment: So where in your code does $destinationDir get assigned? And where do you call receive-job to see if there may have been errors or something other output? Are those just not in the example, or are they missing altogether?

Comment: `$destinationDir` gets assigned outside the example. its pretty straightforward and I know it works because there are no issues when it runs single-threaded. And I dont call `receive-job` because I dont really care about the output.

Comment: The unzip operation using the `Shell.Application` object runs asynchronously. It's not designed for automation.

Comment: add logging to your job, maybe there is some problem with it

Comment: Based on @Bill_Stewart's comment, I would be curious to know if your code still fails when you are not using `Shell.Application`. Try, for example, Mike Robbins' [code sample](http://mikefrobbins.com/2013/08/15/powershell-function-to-unzip-files-using-the-net-framework-4-5-with-fallback-to-com/) to use the .NET 4.5 framework instead.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if your sample is copy pasted or not, but your param is $destinationDir but you reference $destination and then use $destination to create $destinationDir. I'm assuming this is a typo. I fixed your function and it works as you would expect.

```
$unzip = {
    param([string]$sourceFile, [string]$destination)
    #Clean out the destination if it exists
    rmdir $destination -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    mkdir $destination -Force

    #Actual unzip
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipFile = $shell.NameSpace($sourceFile)
    $destinationDir = $shell.NameSpace($destination)
    $destinationDir.copyhere($zipFile.items())
}
```

Using receive-job would have shown you the following errors pointing you in the right direction:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [mkdir], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,mkdir
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'copyhere'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I would still recommend moving away from the comobject for shell.application and to a .Net solution using System.IO.Compression if possible however. Also note that powershell jobs have a hard cap of 5 concurrently running jobs. I'm not sure if this is fixed in v5 or not. CookieMonster wrote an [excellent post](https://ramblingcookiemonster.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/parallel-powershell-part-ii/) and a [function](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel) using runspaces based off some [work by Boe Prox](http://learn-powershell.net/2012/05/13/using-background-runspaces-instead-of-psjobs-for-better-performance/) as a better way of handling concurrency with improved performance.