# Run multiple scripts in parallel

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am stuck at the below task:

I have 5 PowerShell scripts that need to be executed in parallel. I want to create a `home.ps1` that will call to other `test1.ps1`, `test2.ps1`, `test3.ps1`,`test4.ps1` and `test5.ps1` at same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Powershell Run Commands in Parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs.aspx) for this:

```psh
$scripts = 'test1.ps1', 'test2.ps1', 'test3.ps1', 'test4.ps1', 'test5.ps1'

$scripts | ForEach-Object {
  Start-Job -FilePath $_
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

[More information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).