# PowerShell read csv file and create files accordingly

Tags: powershell

Basically, I have a CSV file with a lot of columns. Let's say it looks like this:

```
_username, platform_

username1, platformX1

username2, platformY

username3, platformX2

username4, platformX2

..., ...
```

I would like to write a script that goes through the file and for each platform, it creates a file with the specific username in a different folder, so I would have:

```
\platformX1\username1.file

\platformY\username2.file

\platformX2\username3.file, username4.file

etc etc...
```

I know I should use foreach with an if placed somewhere, but powershell is new for me, and I don't really know how to start it.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Your queston may have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230306/how-to-combine-a-template-with-a-csv-file-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar tweaked to what you want to do.

This created files of a specific size in your directory

```
$data = get-content "C:\Data\masteFile.csv"
$drcty = "C:\Data"

foreach($line in $data)
{
    $a,$b = $line.Split("{,}")
    $parent = $drcty+"\"+$a+"\"
    $filename = $parent + $b.TRIM() +".txt"
    write-host $filename

    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $parent

    fsutil file createnew $filename 2000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do what you want. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
_UserName, Platform_
username1, platformX1
username2, platformY
username3, platformX2
username4, platformX2
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$DestDir = $env:TEMP
$Extension = 'txt'

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $TargetPath = Join-Path -Path $DestDir -ChildPath $IS_Item.Platform_
    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $TargetPath))
        {
        # "$Null = " will supress unwanted output from New-Item
        $Null = New-Item -Path $TargetPath -ItemType Directory
        }

    $FileName = $IS_Item._UserName, $Extension -join '.'
    $FullFileName = Join-Path -Path $TargetPath -ChildPath $FileName

    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $FullFileName))
        {
        # "$Null = " will supress unwanted output from New-Item
        $Null = New-Item -Path $FullFileName -ItemType File
        }
    }
```

i think what it does is apparent, but i know i get ahead of where i otta be at times. so, if there are any questions, please feel free to ask ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

#Path of the CSV file resides
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\data.csv"
$DestinationFolder = "C:\Stuffs"

foreach($record in $csvData)
{
    $destPlatformFolder = $DestinationFolder + "\" + $record.platform_

    if(-not(Test-Path -Path $destPlatformFolder)){

    New-Item -Path $destPlatformFolder -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null

    }

    $destinationFile = $destPlatformFolder + "\" + $record._username

    New-Item -Path $destinationFile -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null
}
```