# BAT or Powershell For loop through CSV to build a URL

Tags: batch-processing

Solved. So my first go at this post was a VERY poorly structured question trying to obfuscate proprietary company information in a very poor manner, and not asking the question well.

Once Walter even got me thinking in the correct direction i worked through the issue. Below was the second issue i was running into and found that the @{key=value} statement was being passed into my url because for some reason my script did not like the header in my csv file. In hindsight, perhaps because i was naming my variable the same as my header. Regardless I worked around it just by using Get-Content rather than Import-CSV.

```
    $aliases = Import-Csv -Path .\aliases.csv

    foreach ($alias in $aliases) {
        Write-Output ('http://www.' + $($alias) + '.mydomain.com') >> urls.txt
```

where the contents of aliases.csv is:

```
    alias
    Matthew
    Mable
    Mark
    Mary
```

This is giving me:

```
    http://www.@{alias=Matthew}.mydomain.com
    http://www.@{alias=Mable}.mydomain.com
    http://www.@{alias=Mark}.mydomain.com
    http://www.@{alias=Mary}.mydomain.com
```

When successful urls.txt should contain:

```
    http://www.Matthew.mydomain.com
    http://www.Mable.mydomain.com
    http://www.Mark.mydomain.com
    http://www.Mary.mydomain.com
```

**NOTE: Edited to clarify use case**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Powershell

```
Get-Content names.txt | %{"Hello, my name is $_. How are you?"}  >> results.txt
```

By the way,  with just a little more effort, you can read more than one variable from a csv file, and substitute all of them for named variables in the text.  This turns out to be very useful in a variety of situations.

**Edit to conform to your edit**

```
Import-csv ./aliases.csv | %{ "http://www.$($_.alias).mydomain.com"}
```

Notes:

1. Once you get used to them, pipelines are the easiest way to process a stream of just about anything.
2. % is an abbreviation of Foreach-Object (not to be confused with foreach).
3. The loop will be done once for each object coming out of the pipe.  Each object will be a PSCustomObject with a single property named alias.
4. $() allows evaluation of a subexpression within a double quoted string.
5. $_ is the current object.
6. the dot, in this context, separates an object specified from a named property.

Comment: CSV! Right, starting to come back now.

I edited the post. I was trying to be vague to obsfucate my use case as it actually contains proprietary information for my company but, i realized that some of it was convoluting the answers, i got an error saying it was the wrong string type.  im trying to iterate over a list of strings, and put each iteration of the string, between two periods, within a URL, so there can be no spaces and there will be a period on either side of the variable.

Comment: Thank you @walter-mitty it had been so long that I wasnt even able to form how I should appropriately ask what I was looking for. I searched for about 30-45 minutes before asking. You mentioning csv flipped my thinking back in the right mode and i was able to work through it.

Comment: You are welcome.  When I was learning Powershell, I wrote a little tool that steps through a CSV file and uses each record to provide variable data for a template.   posted it somewhere here on SO, but I have since rewritten it.

Comment: @walterminty if you've got a link id like to take a link. And I guess, while this solution worked for me, a better solution would be (using my above example) to take a URL that exists: http://www.Jane.mydomain.com and replace jane with the 4 names in the CSV or txt, generating 4 unique URLs, which is what I was trying to accomplish and couldn't figure out so I solved it as seen above. More than one way to skin a cat

Comment: Here is a link to an earlier version of my tool.  I have done a rewrite to make it use pipelines.  The example, posted over in the DBA area generates SQL.  But the tool is easily adapted for use with HTML.  I'm not sure if it's the right tool for your project, but here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230306/how-to-combine-a-template-with-a-csv-file-in-powershell

Comment: You don't need my tool for your case.  Ive editted the answer above.