# Running tasks parallel in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel-processing, task

I have a PowerShell script like this:

```
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    [Do something]
    [Do something]
    [Do something]
}
```

This way one file is treated after the other. I want to treat 4 files at the same time.

I know of the foreach -parallel loop, but that does the [do something] tasks in parallel. I basically want to run the whole foreach loop in parallel.

How can I achieve this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You might look into [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel) or [runspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace(v=vs.85).aspx). Here is an example of Jobs:

```
$block = {
    Param([string] $file)
    "[Do something]"
}
#Remove all jobs
Get-Job | Remove-Job
$MaxThreads = 4
#Start the jobs. Max 4 jobs running simultaneously.
foreach($file in $files){
    While ($(Get-Job -state running).count -ge $MaxThreads){
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3
    }
    Start-Job -Scriptblock $Block -ArgumentList $file
}
#Wait for all jobs to finish.
While ($(Get-Job -State Running).count -gt 0){
    start-sleep 1
}
#Get information from each job.
foreach($job in Get-Job){
    $info= Receive-Job -Id ($job.Id)
}
#Remove all jobs created.
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```

In the above code I have it where each `$file` is running in parallel with eachother (Up to 4 running simultaneously).

EDIT: In response to the comments, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks) is some documentation about scriptblocks. The short reason about why you must include the parameter is because unlike PowerShell functions, scriptblocks can't specify parameters outside of the braces {}.

Comment: Nicely done, though I would recommend using the `Wait-Job` cmdlet instead of all the fancy logic you include to get running jobs and wait for them to complete. [Link to alternative walk-through of runspaces that I personally learned it from and like.](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/)

Comment: Oh, and you should probably explain why you have to pass the `$file` parameter into your scriptblock.

Comment: I'll look into that for future scripts. I had no idea `Wait-Job` existed.

Comment: This method of using jobs is way slower for loading and filtering files. I thought it would be faster because 4 files could be loaded and filtered at the same time. But actually loading and filtering one file after another is a lot faster. How can you explain this? And is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: Would you be willing to add an example using runspaces? I am reading up and trying to convert your Jobs example to use runspaces but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 16):

Powershell 7 introduces `foreach-object -parallel`:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/

Your script would then say

```bsh
$files | ForEach-Object -parallel {
    [Do something]
    [Do something]
    [Do something]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [`Get-Help about_Foreach-Parallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel), `ForEach -Parallel...` will process the entire scriptblock in parallel for each item, but the commands in the scriptblock will be processed sequentially (though presumably they will be parallelized if bracketed with `Parallel {...}`). However, your script must be a PowerShell workflow for this to be accepted; the `Parallel` and `Sequence` keywords are only effective within workflows.

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel : Describes the ForEach -Parallel language construct in Windows PowerShell Workflow. The -Parallel parameter doesn't exist if you're *not* using a workflow. I didn't get the feeling the OP is working with workflows.

Comment: @tommymaynard - Yes, the `Parallel` switch and construct are only applicable to workflows, and I did note that. The querent did mention the `Foreach -parallel` construct in his question, but appeared to misunderstand the effect, so I assumed that a workflow was a possibility, and answered on that basis. If he's not, the job solution that Curious One gave might be the way to go.

Comment: You're absolutely right, you did mention workflows. Sorry about that!