# Refreshing multiple Excel workbooks in parallel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to automate a routine task that involves opening a few Excel files in separate instances and refresh them simultaneously.
If I use RefreshAll(), it will process each workbook one by one.
Is there a way to refresh multiple Excel workbooks in parallel using PowerShell? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried searching around for running tasks in parallel using powershell? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel may answer your question?

Comment: @JoSSte -- _neat_ - I didn't know PowerShell could do that.

Comment: @Vincent -- why would you have multiple instances of the same workbook open and have a need to refresh them simulataneously?

Comment: @ashleedawg -- I need to refresh multiple workbooks and open each of them in a separate instance

Comment: @Vincent -- Why separate instances?  Why do they need to be refreshed simultaneously?  Is there linked data to outside sources?  Where from?  I'm just trying understand more so that I or others can help you.

Comment: @Vincent - Also please check out [mcve] as well as [ask] for some good tips.

Comment: You could open different excel instances (Applications). The Application will not see the workbooks that are open in the other excel Applications