# Run mysql import in parallel with Foreach-Object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to run this loop asynchronously.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.sql | Foreach-Object {

    $database = $_.Name

    mysql -u root -e "
        DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $database;
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        USE $database;
        SOURCE $database;
    "
}
```

I removed a bunch of unrelated stuff form the code but that's the gist of it.

As I see it from the task manager, this program only uses one of the 12 threads my Ryzen 5 1600 has. I would like to speed things up by running them in parallel.

Comment: How many databases are you doing this with where doing it parallel will make a significant difference in the time required?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Powershell Run Commands in Parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel)