# Fastest way to monitor specific process on multiple computers using powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell, monitoring

I am trying to find a way to check if a specific processs exists on about 200 computers. Right now i am doing this using the command tasklist (get-process doesnt work on some of the computers) but this takes about 3-4 minutes which causes my gui to freeze. How can i multi-thread this check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Powershell Run Commands in Parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for jobs.

In your particular case:

```bsh
$scriptBlock = {
  Get-Process -Name 'SomeProcessName'
}

foreach ($computer in $200Computers)
{
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -AsJob
}

$jobs = Get-Job

# other code goes here.
```