# Powershell Is it possible to start process -wait in parallel

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I tried something like this and it starts one after the other

```
  function start-parallel {  
    workflow work {
      start-process $exe1 -wait
      start-process $exe2 -wait
    }

    work 
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Powershell Run Commands in Parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel)

Comment: no because problem is start-process -wait

Comment: The linked script uses `Start-Job` not `start-process`. Unless I missed something

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ah I don't know anything about Start-Job thanks will look again.

Comment: Note that Windows PowerShell Workflows were introduced in v3, but never really took off. Given that they're [no longer available in PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/), where all future development effort will go, I think it's fair to call it an obsolescent technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't simultaneously *wait* and *not wait*.

What you'll want to do is save the process objects output by `Start-Process -PassThru` to a variable, and then not wait until *after* you've kicked off all the processes:

```
$processes = @(
  Start-Process $exe1 -PassThru
  Start-Process $exe2 -PassThru
  # ...
)

# now wait for all of them
$null = $processes |ForEach-Object WaitForExit
```

Comment: Can't I still use workflow with -PassThru ?